# socket.io ENOTFOUND at 241 clients

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I was trying to benchmark my socket.io server today, when i noticed that the clients receive an ENOTFOUND error as soon as 241 concurrent connections are established.
However, I was reading on other websites about concurrencies up to 1000 clients.

I was testing on a machine with 3GHz and 16GB Ram which wasn't nearly used. So I'm not really sure why the connections fail.

Does anyone know why the server doesn't resond anymore that fast?

I am using node: v0.10.28 and 
socket.io: 0.9.17

```
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND]
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  target: 
   { _socket: null,
     bytesReceived: 0,
     readyState: 0,
     supports: { binary: true },
     _isServer: false,
     url: 'ws://localhost:3001/socket.io/1/websocket/FvzSa7LmLu0Toi7F6OZF',
     protocolVersion: 13,
     _events: 
      { open: [Object],
        message: [Object],
        close: [Object],
        error: [Object] 
      } 
 } }
```

Comment: Could you add a stack trace to your question?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to get the stack trace from this error. However, I tested the same code on Ubuntu and Windows (the previous test was on an iMac) where I got up to 10.000 concurrent connections.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution? Was it a hardware performance issue? @dnns

Comment: As I mentioned, it seemed to be an hardware or OS issue. Once I changed to a different machine with Ubuntu or Windows it worked fine. After that, I haven't tried the Mac again.